# Efficient way to iterate through JSON response in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I have been reviewing the Khan Academy API (https://github.com/Khan/khan-api/wiki/Khan-Academy-API) and it identifies http://www.khanacademy.org/api/v1/topictree as the main API call.  I am using the following code to get a list of categories that represents the same menu structure on the actual website.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
url: "http://www.khanacademy.org/api/v1/topictree",
type: 'GET',
dataType: "json",
success: function(data) {                               
        for(var i = 0; i < data.children.length; i++)
        {                       
            //$("#mylist").append("<a href='http://myurl.com/Courses.html?CatId="+data.children[i].id+"'>"+data.children[i].title+"</a><br/>");             
        }        
    }
  }); 
});
```

I am not able to find the most efficient way to get at the children of a categroy and then print out the value of its url and name.  Everytime I try to call the API my browser hangs since the JSON response is about 40mb of data.  The GITHUB site at https://github.com/Khan/khan-api/wiki/Khan-Academy-API mentions that you should filter by topic but the examples provided are not at the root level so I am unable to determine the relationship of the partent to child.

Can someone help me find an efficient way to parse the JSON response and get the children value for each top level category?  Also, what tools do you use to iterate through API calls and JSON responses before committing any code?  Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: It doesn't matter how you iterate over the data, downloading 40MB sounds like deal breaker.

Comment: Right, but wouldn't the size problem be removed if I was able to apply filter criteria to the root - http://www.khanacademy.org/api/v1/topictree?  That is why I am trying to figure out the logic of what to append to the root API call.

Comment: Right, but that depends on that service's API and has nothing to do with JavaScript or JSON.

Comment: I understand that and that is why I was asking for input on parsing the specific API http://www.khanacademy.org/api/v1/topictree and comment on parsing options.

Comment: I don't think I understand what "parsing the API" means in this case.

Comment: If you call the API http://www.khanacademy.org/api/v1/topictree then what are the recommended filters to append to the API call in order to efficiently get the list of courses associated to a course category.  When you see the JSON response you will notice that Khan Academy puts everything as a topic and my browser keeps crashing so I can not do local testing to actually step through the JSON response and figure out what filter criteria to apply to the API call.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80955/discussion-between-blackberry-special-and-felix-kling).

Comment: So you simply want to know whether the API accepts additional parameters and how to use them. That has nothing to do with parsing. This question seems to be more appropriate for a Kahn Academy developer support channel (if something like this exists). I doubt that there are many users here who have used the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Also, what tools do you use to iterate through API calls and JSON responses before committing any code?

If you're asking for tools to examine the response of the request to the API before you start coding, the google chrome extension [Advances Rest Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) is designed for just that. There are most likely equivalent extensions for other mainstream browsers.